# Tableview reloadData() doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Can anyone help me? I'm using a tableView and trying to fill it with values entered by user using a Bar Button item, but whenever I click on save alert action, self.tableView.reloadData() doesn't work !

The code is as below:

```
import UIKit  
class ViewController: UIViewController {  
var names:[String]=[]  
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!  
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    self.title="The List"  
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
"Cell")  
}  

@IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {  
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name",  
                                  message: "Add a new name",  
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)  

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",  
                                   style: .default) {  
                                    [unowned self] action in  

                                    guard let textField = 
                                    alert.textFields?.first,  
                                        let nameToSave = textField.text 
                                         else {  
                                            return  
                                    }  

                                    self.names.append(nameToSave)  
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()  
    }  

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",  
                                     style: .default)  

    alert.addTextField()  

    alert.addAction(saveAction)  
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)  

    present(alert, animated: true)  

}  
}  
extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource{  
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
   Int) -> Int {  
    return names.count  
}  
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell {  

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
  "Cell",for: indexPath)  
        cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]  
        return cell  
  }  
}
```

can anyone find the bug?

Comment: Did you set delegate/datasource ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend verifying that a datasource method (for example, numberOfRowsInSection) is being called upon first load of that view controller. Thus you'll know that you indeed set up the datasource appropriately before checking whether reloadData gets called when you tap 'Save' alert action. I setup a project with your code and everything works fine: added a name in the UIAlertController, tapped 'Save', reloadData was called, and the table displayed the new name. Just add this to viewDidLoad:

`tableView.dataSource = self`

Also make sure that your tableview cell has its reuse identifier designated in interface builder. Select the table view cell and in the Attributes inspector make sure the 'identifier' field is populated with the same name you've set in code (e.g., forCellReuseIdentifier).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delegate/data source in order to use the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods.

You can either do it in the Interface Builder, right click on your table view, and link delegate/datasource to your ViewController.

Or you can do it in code in your viewDidLoad :

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: I set it by dragging from tableView to viewController yellow icon and clicked both delegate & datasource but still doesn't work